# Loop through multiple divs using VBA

Tags: html, vba, dom, getelementbyid, getelementsbyname

I am trying to extract information from a HTML page using Vb script. This is the HTML page from which I am trying to extract the information.

```
<div id="profile-education">

  <div class="position  first education vevent vcard" id="xxxxxx">
  University 1
  <span class="degree">Ph.D.</span>
  <span class="major">Computer Science</span>
  <p class="period">
  <abbr class="dtstart" title="2005-01-01">2005</abbr> &#8211; <abbr class="dtend" 
  title="2012-12-31">2012</abbr>
  </div>          

  <div class="position  education vevent vcard" id="xxxxxx">  
  University 2                  
  <span class="degree">M.Eng.</span> 
  <span class="major">Computer Science</span>
  <p class="period">
  <abbr class="dtstart" title="2000-01-01">2000</abbr> &#8211; <abbr class="dtend" 
  title="2004-12-31">2004</abbr>
  </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to extract the information in the below format.

- University Name: University 1
- Degree Name: Phd
- Major: Computer Science
- Period: 2005 - 2012
- University Name: University 2
- Degree Name: M.Eng
- Major: Computer Science
- Period: 2000 - 2004

In my VB script, I have the following code which extracts the entire information as a single variable.

```
Dim openedpage as String
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-education").innerText
```

However, if I use the following statement in my vb Script, I can get a particular span information.

```
openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-education").getElementsByTagName("span")
(0).innerText
```

The above code gives me Phd as the output. However, I will not know the total spans beforehand and so I cannot simply give span(0) and span(1) in my code. Also, I would like to extract the information for all div tags and I won't be knowing this information either. Basically, I want some loop structure to iterate through the div tags with the id **profile-education** from which I should be able to extract multiple div and span information.

Comment: Are you using vbscript or VBA? They're not exactly the same...

Comment: I use excel with VBA. Sorry for not mentioning it clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim divs, div

set divs = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-education").getElementsByTagName("div")

for each div in divs
    debug.print "*************************************"
    debug.Print div.ChildNodes(0).toString
    debug.print div.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    debug.print div.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
    '  etc...
next div
```

Comment: I am getting NULL as the output. I am not getting any value returned. When I tried printing divs value, I am getting [object HTMLDivElement] as output.

Comment: I still get NULL only.. I am not sure of where am doing wrong. This is my code.                                                 openedpage = iedoc1.getElementById("profile-education").getElementsByTagName("div")                                                                     For Each div In openedpage
MsgBox div.ChildNodes(0).toString
MsgBox div.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
MsgBox div.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
Next div

Comment: I tested with the exact HTML you posted in your question.  Are you not using `Set opendpage = ...` ? You need to use **Set** for assigning values to object variables.

Comment: Tim, Thanks again. Now, I am getting the proper values after assigning to object variables. However, I do not get the University 1 and University 2 as output. Also, I am not able to get the periods as output.

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned it clearly. The university name is inside <h3> tag and then the <div> tag starts. I have this information from a public profile page of linkedin. Suppose, if you search in linkedin for a particular person XXX and in the opened page, we have this HTML format for which I am trying to extract the data. Due to privacy issues, I am not able to post the exact HTML code that am using.

Comment: This is the link to my public profile page. I wish to extract the profile education details corresponding to my profile as I mentioned in my original question. http://www.linkedin.com/pub/ramesh-venkataraman/63/621/b42

Comment: The code I posted should give you a good start: if you have further problems then it might be appropriate to post a new question including your current code, along with what errors you're getting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30368/discussion-between-ramesh-and-tim-williams)

Comment: I am using a counter and getElementsbyClassName to extract the exact information that I need. It works fine for me. Thanks a lot.